# How to repaint() a component in Java

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to create a `JComponent` class with a `paintComponent()` that can be instantiated in another class and can invoke its own `repaint()` method?

```
class A extends JComponent {
     @Override
     paintComponent(){//code here
     }
}

class B {
    static public A temp = new A();

    void someMethod() {
     if (something)
       temp.repaint(); //will this repaint this particular 
                       //component if it was in a JFRAME    
     else if (something)
        //do not repaint
          else if (anothersomething)
             temp.repaint();
}
```

Comment: static method in class A may help ?

Comment: If you have a reference to a component, then you can invoke repaint() on the component. If the component is displayed in a visible GUI then it will repaint itself.

Comment: If the component is visible and added to a JPanel which is added to a JFrame the component can be repainted(). Then I can just call the repaint() method from the variable name.    myVariable.repaint() which can be called from any location in the code, and it should repaint what ever is in the paintComponent() method.

Comment: The method in Class A i do not think has to be static because it is the overridden paintComponent() from the JComponent class.